# "Object {} has no method 'cast' error" when trying to add item to mongoose array

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to create a todo app using node.js, mongoose and backbone for learning purposes.
Up till now I defined these models:

```
var TaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type:String },
    content: { type:String } ,
    created: {type:Date, 'default':Date.now},
    due: {type:Date},
    accountId: {type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId}
});

var Task = mongoose.model('Task',TaskSchema);

var AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: { type:String, unique: true},
    password: { type:String } ,
    name: { first: {type:String}, 
        last: { type:String } },
    birthday: {
        day: {type:Number, min:1, max:31, required:false},
        month: {type:Number, min:1, max:12, required:false},
        year: {type:Number}

    },
    photoUrl: {type:String},
    biography:{type:String},
    tasks:[Task]
});

var Account = mongoose.model('Account',AccountSchema);
```

In addition, I also have the following method for **adding a task**:

```
var enter_new_task = function(options,callback){
    var title = options.title;
    var content = options.content;
    var due = options.due;
    var account = options.account;
    var task = new Task({
        title: title,
        content: content,
        due: due,
        accountId: account._id
    });
    account.tasks.push(task);
    account.save(function(err) {
        if ( err ) {
            console.log("Error while saving task: " + err);
        }else{
            callback();
        }
    })
}
```

But when I indeed add a task, I get an error that says:

> "Object {} has no method 'cast'"

With the following stack trace:

```
   at Array.MongooseArray._cast (/home/lior/workspace/todo_express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/array.js:107:30)
    at Object.map (native)
    at Array.MongooseArray.push (/home/lior/workspace/todo_express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/array.js:261:23)
    at Object.enter_new_task (/home/lior/workspace/todo_express/models/Account.js:107:17)
    at /home/lior/workspace/todo_express/app.js:104:18
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/lior/workspace/todo_express/models/Account.js:41:4)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/lior/workspace/todo_express/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:162:8)
    at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Promise.emit (/home/lior/workspace/todo_express/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:79:38)
    at Promise.fulfill (/home/lior/workspace/todo_express/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:92:20)
9
```

It seems that the problem is with the line that the new task to the tasks array.

Couldn't find anything on google or stack so I wonder, does anyone have an idea about what went wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `tasks:[TaskSchema]` instead of "Task" in the AccountSchema definition?

Comment: you are correct... write it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The error is in the AccountSchema definition. A subdocument type should be a schema, not a model.

```
var AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    //...
    tasks:[TaskSchema]
});
```

Comment: You could also do `Somemodel.schema` which is what I usually do

Comment: This was so on point!  It definitely fixed my issue.  I had trouble finding this though since my stack trace also had "undefined is not a function" in it and the _cast error was somewhat buried in the stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you don't have direct access to your schema, and only have access to the model, you can access the model's schema with dot notation like this:

```
var AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    //...
    tasks:[Task.schema]
});
```

This is helpful if you've defined your schema in another file and are using something like this:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', TaskSchema);
```